# Datatable column names

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on an app where I am performing lots of SQL queries. At the moment I am trying to populate a combobox with the result of an SQL query where I am getting all of the table names in a database using this code:

```
tablesComboBox.DataSource = dataLayer.Query("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES");
tablesComboBox.DisplayMember = "TABLES";
```

and

```
public DataTable Query(string sql)
        {
            var result = new DataTable();
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                result.Load(command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
            }
            return result;
        }
```

My problem is that I cannot populate the combobox as I do not know the column name(s) of the returned datatable and cannot figure out how to access it. "TABLES" does not work. I'm sure there is a simple answer but am currently at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think you need the data table name. you just need the column name for the tables.
try this.

```
tablesComboBox.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
```

p.s. to optimize your code, you could really do this and just get the table names:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME <> 'sysdiagrams'
```

Comment: That works great thanks, although I am also getting a 'System Table'. Do you know off hand how to exclude System Tables from the query?

Comment: I found I can exclude it using WHERE TABLE_NAME <> 'sysdiagrams' but would like to know if there is a generic way to exclude system tables.

Comment: most system tables follow an object id value of less than 100 and are not shown by SQL to users in the above query. Except for this 1 table sysdiagrams, which was added later by some uber team in Microsoft. hence, SQL treats it as any other table. this should be the only such stand-out table so you can do a where clause to eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the column names for a table, use

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='your table'
```

Answer (score 0):

The details of the columns returned by your query above can be read [from this link.](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/196/informationschematables/)

However, if you are interested only in your table names you should add a condition to your query above

```
 DataTable t = myQuery(@"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'");
```

And of course, the DisplayMember property should be set to

```
 tablesComboBox.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
```